# How to print csv from list and string combination without delimiter of space?

Tags: python, django, string, list

my csv file is created using values from a table as:

```
with open(fullpath,'wb') as csvFile:
                    writer = csv.writer(csvFile,delimiter='|',
                                        escapechar=' ',
                                        quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

string_values = 'abc|xyz|mno'

for obj in queryset.iterator():
     writer.writerow([
                 smart_str(obj.code),#code
                 smart_str(string_values),# string of values
                 ])
```

The csv generated should output result as:

```
code1|abc|xyz|mno
```

but what is generated is:

```
code1|abc |xyz |mno
```

I am unable to remove the space from the string while creating the csv. in whatever way may be. The string values are generated dynamically and can have 1 or more string values. I cannot use quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE without specyfying escapechar=' '  i.e a space. Please suggest.

Comment: what is `smart_str`?

Comment: from django.utils.encoding import smart_str

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just write strings containing the delimiter, unescaped!

Use, instead:

```
string_values = 'abc|xyz|mno'.split('|')

for obj in queryset.iterator():
     writer.writerow([smart_str(obj.code)] + string_values)
```

IOW, `writerow` a **list** of strings, and let the `writer` insert the delimiters between the strings in the list!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli you truely are a genius and saved my day!